# CSS renders differently from localhost to webserver

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome, firefox

I am building a webapp with django, react, and material-ui. I am facing the same issue with firefox and chrome. On my localhost, the css looks fine. But when I load it to the webserver, a few things are wrong:

1. Material UI field labels are smushed down in production.
2. h3 element is bigger in production
3. Material UI button is not full width in production

I have read about adjusting the zoom levels on the browser directly, but since it is only effecting a few elements (the main containers on the screen are fine) I don't think this is the problem.

Another question suggested to ensure the meta tags are the same, which they're not exactly, but they're not different in a way that is obvious to me it would cause this.

The following is the meta tags for both production and development.

production meta (based off of chrome dev tools)

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

development meta (based off chrome dev tools)

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
<meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app">
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"> (not in production)
```

The only difference I see is the `viewport` in development has `minimum-scale=1`. When I add that directly to my production code from the dev tools, the problem persists. The link to `manifest` is also not in production, but I am assuming `react build` accounts for this file.

Any ideas, I really don't want to maintain two code sources at this granular of a level. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

In my django application I am importing bootstrap 5 at the top level html file, which I am embedding my React/ CSS scripts in. Bootstrap is interfering with my React css which is based on Material-UI.

There might be a better solution, but I just maintain 2 `base.html` files in my django application, one with bootstrap that handles my django related files, and one for my embedded react project.